# Saturated voltage of LF351 op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

So the LF351 has an output voltage swing of typically 12V. To achieve an undistorted output waveform, output swing should be lower than Vsat. How do I know what the Vsat is? Its not mentioned anywhere in datasheets or is the output voltage swing=Vsat?

Comment: It is not typically 12V. It is not a fixed voltage. It depends on supply voltage. It how close it can get to the voltage rail, a minimum distance above the negative rail and below the positive rail. See Output voltage range in the datasheet and note the supply voltage used for the entire table. It is that voltage difference.

Comment: [This Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/508704/how-to-choose-resistor-values-in-op-amps/508708#508708) should help.

Comment: Ok so my invertinng op-amp is supposed to amplify a 50Khz 0.5Vpp to 25Vpp so the gain is 50 and drives a 2kOhm load. What should my supply voltage be? Also what should be the values at the feedback resistor and the resistor at Vin.

Comment: Are you studying with @BeatriceUK - she asked that question earlier today. My answer gives you the details you need.

Comment: Yea just saw your answers, its clearer to me now. But how does the supply voltage affect voltage swing? In the datasheet its states output swing is 12V when Vs= 15. What would the output swing be if Vs= 18V? Would it be 15V?

Comment: VS=18 V is at the absolute maximum ratings. So you might be lucky, or you might find your output voltage = 0 V permanently. It's best to stay a few volts below absolute max, at the recommended operating voltage. or do you feel lucky, punk?

Comment: Not a very lucky person Neil