# Choosing op-amps

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

I am choosing an op-amp to receive a 50kHz 0.5Vpp signal and amplify it with a gain of 50. What parameters/factors do I consider when choosing between different op-amps. All I know is the slew rate of the amplifier. Not too sure in other parameters such as GBW?

Comment: Kind of an incomplete description. What is the accuracy requirement? Is it a 50kHz sine wave or a square wave (much higher harmonics present)? And many other factors such as supply rails etc.

Comment: Its a sine wave, no accuracy requirements

Comment: [Quite similar to this asked two days ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/508704/how-to-choose-resistor-values-in-op-amps/508708#508708).

Comment: What’s the signal (input and output) max and min values? How close are those to your available supply rails?

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of information, a sine wave output of 25 volts p-p at 50 KHZ is something useful. It means a bi-polar supply of +/- 15 volts, just enough for a bjt output to reach +/- 12.5 volts. You are running the op-amps output close to full voltage when you include a -1.2 volt drop from each supply rail.

Full power at 50 KHZ means a comfy GBW of 100 times that value, or 5 MHZ. A GBW of at least 1 MHZ would be a big help. A single op-amp in an 8-pin package gives you DC offset adjustments as well, even if you do not use this feature.

Low cost op-amps would be the TL051/TL061/TL071/TL081 series. The TL051 has low noise and a slew-rate of 20 V/us, and a minimum GBW of 2.8 MHZ. The OPAxx and ADxxx series has better slew rates, high-current and high-voltage versions but they cost much more than the TL0xx series.

As for gain resistors, please read the tons of online documents. 10K ohm is a common minimum safe input value as it does not load down most signal sources. 50 times that value (to set your gain) is 500 K ohms, to be placed between the output pin and the (-) input pin. As for inverting or non-inverting input, read the op-amps datasheet.

These are simple examples of inverting and non-inverting op-amps. Note that non-inverting may need a trim-pot to get a gain of 50.00.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEdywb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

> It's a sine wave, no accuracy requirements

In that case:

The right choice of opamp would be **Piece of Dirt™** opamp: with it's Commonly-Found-On-Ground technology, **Piece of Dirt™** is unparalleled in costing less. It's specs are pretty good: proper output biasing can make your output root mean square error be *exactly* the standard deviation of your signal! No other technology does that at a lower price or lower power consumption than **Piece of Dirt™**!!

---

On a serious note, with this level of information you can literally not recommend any component.

You'll need to figure out, at least:

- Available Supply
- In- and output voltage ranges
- cost constraints
- Noise constraints
- Bias constraints

And once you have that, we could help you (if product recommendation questions weren't off-topic).

However, once you've determined that, it will be trivial to go to e.g. digikey.com, put in these numbers in the parameter constraints for the opamp product list and do it yourself.

Without these numbers, you can't be helped.

So: figure out how to infer these constraints from what you're trying to build!

Comment: @Sparky256 that was supposed to be a humorous take on the lack of requirements engineering. I wasn't referring to the quality of the opamp, but was making the analogy that in the absence of any requirements for the opamp, an isolating piece of dirt can fulfill the same job. (notice how the error calculation applies to anything with a constant output.)

Comment: I found it humorous but, your talents may be wasted on these boards if folk are too serious.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks! To be fair, the misunderstanding was predictable, and I could have went with **Small Piece of Rock™** instead and made the same joke; the fact that "piece of dirt" has such a negative connotation eluded me at the point.

Comment: I remember Nat Semi announcing their range of "Damn fast" devices - it was the [LH0063C](http://www.repeater-builder.com/humor/pdfs/national-lh0033c-damn-fast.pdf). On that basis I'd have called the op-amp above **DamnCrap** \$^{TM}\$.

Comment: This made my morning, @Andyaka :)

Comment: I did not DV you Marcus. It was done before I posted an answer. Some here have harsh judgment.