# Considerations in resistor sizing for op-amp circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, resistors

For a basic op-amp amplifier circuit, the gain is determined by the ratio of the input to feedback resistors, which is trivial to calculate, but how do I know what actual value to go with? For an inverting amplifier of gain -10, for example, I could do 1ohm and 10ohm, or I could do 10Mohm and 100Mohm, both gives -10 gain, but I assume would behave differently in various applications.

So my question is, what considerations should be taken when choosing what value for the resistors?
Here's a few of my assumptions, please correct any of these that are wrong;

- Higher resistance means higher input impedance and lower energy consumption for the circuit.
- Lower resistance means more resilient to outside interference.
- Higher resistance means more consideration needs to be taken with PCB
  design characteristics like trace inductance and receiving
  interference from power lines.
- Lower resistance means more consideration needs to be taken with PCB
  design characteristics like trace thickness and sending interference to
  signal lines.
  I'm certain there are good guides out there on this, but I don't really know what to look up to find some, so if anyone has any suggestions for resources I can look at, that would be awesome.

I'm basically looking for good design principles for resistor sizing, specifically in this case for op-amp circuits, but also just in general.  Any good rule-of-thumbs or resources would be much appreciated.

I'm not looking for "be reasonable about it" or "copy values from similar circuits without knowing why". I'm looking for "if you're input signal is weak and in the low MHz range, go with resistors in the 100Ks range" or "if the output needs to drive a 100m long cable, go with the 1Ks range". They type of guidelines that experienced designers would intuitively know and use to steer their designs.

Comment: *I could do 1ohm and 10ohm* No you could not as most opamps cannot drive an impedance as low as 11 Ohm. *or I could do 10Mohm and 100Mohm* And then you would have a huge DC offset if the opamp does not have (MOS)FET inputs and the circuit would be very sensitive to disturbances as the impedance is so high. So you need to use "sensible" values like 1k ohm and 10 kohm.

Comment: *Lower resistance means more consideration needs to be taken with PCB design characteristics like trace thickness* For an opamp feedback, if PCB resistance is an issue, you're using too low value resistors. So this is a non-issue. *and sending interference to signal lines.* That is actually only an issue when using too high resistor values.

Comment: *I'm basically looking for good design principles for resistor sizing* Stay above 1 kohm and below 1 Mohm. Only go outside that range if you have **a good reason to do so**. Also **look at many circuits designed by others** then simply do the same. There is no need to over-think this in such detail. Also following "general rules" or "rules of thumb" is OK for most cases. But for the designs where those rules are no good, it is better to **understand why** you should not apply those rules in that particular case.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 11ohms at say 3.3V is 300mA, I'm sure there is an op-amp somewhere that can supply 300mA, but I think you understand what I'm trying to say and you're being antagonistic for no reason.  Is it more 'sensible' to use 1K or 100K? Both are perfectly reasonable values that I've seen used before.  Understanding the why is important, but I'm looking for a starting point here. If I have a circuit for amplifying a 10MHz signal, there has to be a better way to choose values than googling '10MHz amp circuit' and picking a typical value.  I'm looking for a guide or set of guidelines.

Comment: *there has to be a better way to choose values than googling '10MHz amp circuit' and picking a typical value.* OK, then please tell me what that way is. The thing is, I know, **from experience** that 10 MHz is quite a high frequency for an opamp. So you would need to use a wide-band opamp. In the datasheet of such an opamp the typical application circuits usually have low impedances, like 50 ohms. Can you guess why that is? Probably not and that is why **for a beginner** it is a better idea to look at existing designs. Hey, these resistors are only 50 ohms, why is that?

Comment: As a beginner you don't realize yet that at 10 MHz, the parasitic capacitances that are everywhere, start to play a role. So if you'd use 10 k resistors, in combination with those parasistic caps, will limit the bandwidth to much less than 10 MHz so your amplifier will not work. At 50 ohms the cutoff frequency becomes much higher and the circuit can work with 10 MHz. That are the details you don't know yet as a beginner. So unless you want to fall in all those traps, learn from existing circuits.

Comment: Things like power dissipation, noise and input bias current of the op-amp play a role too.

Comment: *I'm looking for a guide or set of guidelines* And I'm telling you that there are none. Designing circuits isn't about "following guidelines". It is about understanding. That understanding comes with experience and studying / understanding the work of other (more experienced) designers. That 10 MHz was just an example. Depending on the application other things come into play like @LarsHankeln mentiones. Which of those are  important and what tradoffs can be made cannot be put in "guidelines". It's a multi-dimensional puzzle that a designer needs to solve.

Comment: So the only way for a beginner to properly design a circuit is to assume that someone has already properly designed a similar circuit and go with that?  How do I tell if a circuit is properly designed or not? If there's really no other way to do it, then that's how I'll do it, but I asked this question in the first place because I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: This has been asked many times in the past, e.g., [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/508704/51760) (found by searching the site for `[operational-amplifier] resistor value is:question`). I'd vote to close this as a duplicate but this is a fairly well written question so it perhaps would be better to close older questions as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: 10 MHz is hard work with an op-amp. Suppliers of op-amps capable of that will have produced Application Notes with reference circuits and guidelines for choosing resistors. Use that resource. 10 MHz is a use case that falls outside 'general guidelines' of 1k to 1M resistors being usually OK. Don't be surprised to see suggested values well below 1k, and of course you'll need the op-amp output current to be able to drive them.

Answer (score 7):

This is a great question from a beginner. You are thinking about good topics.
As mentioned elsewhere, you'd have to think about very low resistances needing a bunch of output power from the op amp to supply feedback (or even meaningful signal) when you have single-digit or low double-digit resistor values in the signal path and feedback loop.

On the other extreme, very high values (multi meg ohms), means it may take some time to charge the capacitance if JFET inputs or for BJT inputs, you may have very large input offset issues.

In general, I keep each stage in the range of 10k to 100k for input resistor and 10k to 1M for feedback resistor. Again, that is "in general".

If you have a voltage divider network controlling the DC offset to your input, "low-value" input and feedback resistors can interfere with your voltage divider network. So, low value is a relative term and your mileage may vary.

Remember that lower values are good for faster circuits and higher values are good for low power.  Precision is effected in both extremes - high value resistor in input snd feedback can be amplified by input offset currents while low values can interfere with any DC offset voltage divider networks.

Comment: "In general, I keep each stage in the range of 10k to 100k for input resistor and 10k to 1M for feedback resistor. Again, that is "in general"." That's very much the sort of answer I was hoping for, thanks for your input!

Comment: A more advanced topic, there's also [thermal noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson-Nyquist_noise) considerations regarding the resistors. If you are designing a low noise amplifier, you want to use low value resistors, but still stay within power budget.

Comment: @qrk True if noise *voltage* is the issue. If noise *current* is the issue, you go for high value resistors. And if noise *power* is the issue, the resistance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

> - Higher resistance means higher input impedance and lower energy
>   consumption for the circuit.

Yes, higher input impedance is helped by using high-resistances **in an inverting amplifier**. A non-inverting amplifier can use low-value resistors, and *still have* high input impedance. Instrumentation amplifiers might use a non-inverting stage(s) at its input(s), for example.

> - Lower resistance means more resilient to outside interference.

Possibly, where interference is local electric fields.
 Suppose your input is troubled by a ground loop (a common problem). Low resistances can sometimes mean that more of the ground-line noise on long input cables will appear across a low-value input resistor.
 It is sometimes possible to *add a series resistor* in the ground path to decrease noise current, and also to cause these currents to mostly cause a voltage drop across this resistor. It is then possible to discriminate this voltage from the input signal.

Going to too-low resistors make wire resistance and printed-circuit resistance more important. Where amplifier output currents are high, some output current can find its way back to amplifier input: oscillations can result, or cause peaks at some frequency. Low-value resistors should cause you to design ground paths with considerable care.

> - Higher resistance means more consideration needs to be taken with PCB
>   design characteristics like trace inductance and receiving
>   interference from power lines.

OK - power lines are high-voltage (often including high-frequency garbage) that can couple electric fields into high-impedance amplifiers. **Capacitance** rather than inductance is more important as the coupling mechanism. Inductance from loop currents are more a problem in low-resistance circuits.

---

What's considered low resistance where tiny input signals might be tainted by amplifier noise? Look at the amplifier's **voltage noise** and compare with **current noise**.

For example, a randomly-chosen low-noise opamp claims voltage noise of \${5.5 nV}\over{\sqrt{Hz}}\$ and current noise of \${1.5 fA}\over{\sqrt{Hz}}\$

- Resistances around this op amp higher than 3.6Meg tend to make current noise sources dominant
- Resistances around this op amp lower than 3.6Meg tend to make voltage noise sources dominant.

I would use this CMOS op amp in a transimpedance amplifier where a photo-diode provides tiny input currents, and feedback resistor is a large-value (to give high gain). An op amp with bipolar input transistors rather than CMOS input transistors likely has too much current noise.

---

An op amp might limit its output current at ten(s) of milliamps for self-protection. Suppose it runs from +/- 15V DC supplies. Not only must the op amp drive a load resistance (with current), but it must drive a feedback resistor too. A feedback resistor lower than 1500 ohms might trigger the op amp's internal current-limiter. And it will raise chip temperature, causing drift.

Comment: A lot of good info here that I hadn't thought of, thank you very much for writing this all up!

Comment: it should read 1.5 pA/rtHz

Comment: @tobalt Whoops, my bad...went back to that random data sheet and discovered it was a CMOS opamp having \${1.5fA}\over{\sqrt{Hz}}\$ noise spec (blush). That makes it fairly good choice for the transimpedance example circuit. Thank you (2nd edit in progress).

Answer (score 3):

> *For an inverting amplifier of gain -10, for example, I could do 1 ohm
> and 10 ohm*

For an inverting op-amp amplifier there is a virtual ground at the inverting terminal. This is made to look like ground (the same as the voltage on the non-inverting input) because of the process of negative feedback. If you don't understand this then I encourage you to study it.

This means that the feedback resistor can be regarded as connected between output and the virtual ground. So, if you wanted an output signal of 1 volt and, the feedback resistor was 1 Ω it would force a current of 100 mA into the virtual ground in order to maintain that virtual ground close to the voltage level on the non-inverting input (usually 0 volts).

Do you want to waste this amount of current? Can the op-amp supply that amount of current? The answers are almost certainly "no" in 99% of all op-amp circuits.

For pretty much identical reasons, do you want the input impedance of your inverting op-amp circuit to be 1 Ω because that is what a virtual ground delivers to you.

> *or I could do 10 Mohm and 100 Mohm*

Input leakage currents (circa 1 nA) would produce a voltage offset error of 10 mV which would be multiplied by the gain to produce an output error of -100 mV. Do you want that to happen?

Clearly there are op-amps that have a much lower leakage current but, these come with a price-tag that reflects that superiority.

Also, with maybe 1 pF parasitic capacitance across a 100 MΩ feedback capacitor, the output cut-off frequency would be 1.59 kHz. Wouldn't you expect many op-amp applications to service bandwidths up to several MHz let alone audio? How would that happen with a 100 MΩ feedback resistor.

Comment: So considering things like wasted power, how much current the op-amp can supply, effects from leakage currents and parasitic capacitance/inductance/resistance, all very good things to look at, thank you

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that it depends on frequency. Component interconnections (circuit traces, cables, ...) tend to have characteristic impedances of ~100 Ω. Below the characteristic impedance, inductive parasitics limit your frequency response. Above it, capacitive parasitics dominate. If you look at example circuits, impedances (and thus resistor values) commonly approach 50 or 100 Ω as you look at circuits for higher frequencies/wider bandwidths.

If you're trying to conserve power, higher frequency favors lower voltage circuitry rather than higher resistance. Since noise voltage declines with declining resistance, signal/noise ratio doesn't (theoretically) suffer from a scaled reduction of impedance and voltage. However, "God is in the details."